# Python: How do I make it so that an input has to match the input entered previously

Tags: python

this is my first day of coding in python so I don't know how "clean" my code is. I am trying to make a fun piece of code, that makes you add your name, and correctly re-enter it right after

```
name = input ("Insert name:")
print ("re-enter your name")
answer = name
if answer == name
    print ("excellent")
elif
    print ("You have entered the wrong name")
    exit()
```

Comment: ```answer=input("re-enter your name")```. ```answer = name```, this is like you are yourself assigning ```name``` to ```answer```. And no need of ```exit()```. The code itself will terminate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you create variable answer = name, the result will always be true because the answer variable and name variable will have the same contents in memory.

Oh yes, I ran your code and there was an error. After the code if some_condition must be added a colon after it in one line, elif is like that, in using elif you must have a conditional after elif and then a colon. If you only have one conditional for the if, then use else instead of elif.

Here's your code after fixing:

```
name = input("Insert name:")
answer = input("re-enter your name")
if answer == name:
    print ("excellent")
else:
    print ("You have entered the wrong name")
    exit()
```

CMIWW

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a second input to re-enter your name. `answer=name` is basically assigning `answer` `name`. So you will always end up with `answer==name`

Also, a colon missing after `if...`. The `elif` statement is completely useless. You might want to use `else` there because you only want `answer==name` else redirect them to `You have entered the wrong name`

```
name = input ("Insert name: ")
answer = input("re-enter your name: ")
if answer == name:
    print ("excellent")
else:
    print ("You have entered the wrong name")
```

Output 1:

```
Insert name: John
re-enter your name: jon
You have entered the wrong name
```

Output 2:

```
Insert name: Mike
re-enter your name: Mike
excellent
```

Answer (score 0):

```
name = input("Insert your nme : ")
rename_name = input("Re-enter your name : ")
if name == rename_name:
    print("excellent")
else:
    print("You have entered the wrong name")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear whether objective is just to verify that second entry is same as first or make sure that they match. If latter then second input must be in loop ('while first answer is not equal to second print warning and ask again, if answers match print Excellent') :

```
first = input("Enter your name: ")
while first != input("Enter your name again: "):
    print("Names entered don't match!")
else:
    print('Excellent')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the cleanest code you would like You don't have to exit from condition using any exit function. And in second line, you were just printing "re-enter your name: " not receiving any inputs.

```
name = input ("Insert name: ")
answer = input("re-enter your name: ")
print ("excellent" if answer == name else "You have entered the wrong name")
```